# RESTEasy loses object during serialization

Tags: jaxb, resteasy

Trying to send objects to an endpoint, RESTEasy is dropping some of the objects, replacing them with Ns nulls, which then cause class-cast exceptions.

Here's a simplified test case that shows the problem with the latest version of RESTEasy, and with earlier versions (for example, 2.3.7):

Request class (note that it is a root element):

```
package org.problem;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4057201224391819116L;

    public Request() {
        super();
    }

    // Yes, I could use an adapter to serialize a map, but that's not germane to the problem.
    public List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getArgs() {
        int size = names.size();
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            args.put(names.get(i), values.get(i));
        }
        return args;
    }
}
```

Additional info class (also a root element):

```
package org.problem;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AdditionalInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4286757723357099359L;

    public AdditionalInfo() {
        super();
    }

    public String value;
}
```

Endpoint:

```
package org.problem;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/problem/")
public class Endpoint {
    @POST
    @Path("example/v1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String doProblem(Request request) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = request.getArgs().get("info");
            AdditionalInfo info = (AdditionalInfo)obj;
            return info.value;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected " + AdditionalInfo.class.getCanonicalName() + " but instead got " + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }
    }
}
```

Reproduce problem:

```
package org.problem;

import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class TestProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AdditionalInfo info = new AdditionalInfo();
        info.value = "Got The Info";
        Request request = new Request();
        request.names.add("info");
        request.values.add(info);
        // To see that AdditionalInfo has to be specifically added to JAXB context, try running without it:
        // JAXBContext requestContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
        JAXBContext requestContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class, AdditionalInfo.class);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller marshaller = requestContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(request, writer);
        String marshalledRequestString = writer.toString();
        System.out.println(marshalledRequestString);
        InputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(marshalledRequestString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        MockHttpRequest mockRequest = MockHttpRequest.post("/problem/example/v1");
        mockRequest.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        mockRequest.content(xmlStream);
        MockHttpResponse mockResponse = new MockHttpResponse();
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(new POJOResourceFactory(Endpoint.class));
        dispatcher.invoke(mockRequest, mockResponse);
        System.out.println(mockResponse.getStatus());
        String response = mockResponse.getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

When I run that code, I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request>
    <names>info</names>
    <values xsi:type="additionalInfo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <value>Got The Info</value>
    </values>
</request>

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected org.problem.AdditionalInfo but instead got com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.problem.TestProblem.main(TestProblem.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected org.problem.AdditionalInfo but instead got com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
    at org.problem.Endpoint.doProblem(Endpoint.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
    ... 2 more
```

If I remove the AdditionalInfo from the JAXBContext initialization used to create the request body, then it blows up earlier:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class org.problem.AdditionalInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.problem.AdditionalInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:116)
    at org.problem.TestProblem.main(TestProblem.java:31)
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class org.problem.AdditionalInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.problem.AdditionalInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:653)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:342)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.problem.AdditionalInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:593)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:648)
    ... 11 more
```

It looks like the problem might be that RESTEasy isn't initializing the JAXBContext correctly.

The documentation says "Based on the class you are marshalling/unmarshalling, RESTEasy will, by default create and cache JAXBContext instances per class type".

This seems to be an incorrect statement.

Assuming it is incorrect, what is the fix? Do I need to write my own ContextResolver? Is there a way to tell RESTEasy what root elements it needs to be able to serialize?

Even if I tell it, the point of the name/value map was to be able to serialize any arg (provided it is a root element), so having to inform RESTEasy about each new arg type is a maintenance headache, and defeats the point of the name/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create a custom ContextResolver. JAXB automatically determines the matching Context of the resolver based on the expected endpoint data type. Your problem here is that your REST- endpoint expects an instance of `org.problem.Request` but in your main method you are using an object of type `org.problem.AdditionalInfo` as payload. You can try to annotate the `org.problem.Request` class with:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({AdditionalInfo.class})
```

which tells the JAXB framework to treat the type `org.problem.AdditionInfo` also as an possible context type for the expected type `org.problem.Request`

But why your using a `Request` type and a `AdditionalInfo`. Do they have anything in common? You may simplify your endpoint as follows:

```
@Path("/problem/")
public class Endpoint {
    @POST
    @Path("example/v1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String doProblem(AdditionalInfo request) {
    ...
}
```

This would be a bit more straight forward. Also consider the usagae of your JAXB annotations. You can label your XML tags and bind it to a specific namespace by using an annotation like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement", namespace = "SomeNameSpace")
```

Furthermore try to use annotations like:

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "SomeNameSpace")
@XmlAttriubte
```

for the members of your data entities.

---

**JUnit test case, which communicates with the rest endpoint.**

```
@Test
public void a100_insertCustomerOrderTest() throws Exception {
    Customer cust = new Customer(1, "CUST", "OMER", "sb@gmail.com", "sb",
            lastLoginTime);
    List<Product> products = new Vector<Product>();
    products.add(new Book(5, "asdf", "description", 0, currency, isbn, new Date(),
            "asdf"));
    CustomerOrder custOrder = new CustomerOrder(cust, bookingOrder,
            products);

    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(BASE_URL, sslExecutor_schusb);
    request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, custOrder);
    ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());

    String expectedLink = BasicServiceTest.BASE_URL+"booking/6";
    insertedResourceLink = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Location");
    assertEquals(expectedLink, insertedResourceLink);

    response.releaseConnection();
    request.clear();
}
```

Below there are the data entities `Product` and `Book`

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Book.class})
public class Product implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Constructor needed by JAXB, in order to marshal a {@link Product} into
     * {@link Book}
     * 
     * @param product
     *            {@link Product}
     */
    protected Product(Product product) {
        setId(new Integer(product.getId()));
        setName(new String(product.getName()));
        setDescription(new String(product.getDescription()));
        setPrice(new Integer(product.getPrice()));
        setCurrency(new String(product.getCurrency()));
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
public class Book extends Product implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Constructor needed by JAXB in order to marshal a {@link Product} into a
     * {@link Book} instance
     * 
     * @param product
     *            {@link Product}
     */
    public Book(Product product) {
        super(product);
        Book book = (Book) product;

        setIsbn(new String(book.isbn));
        setPublicationDate(new Date(book.getPublicationDate().getTime()));
        setAuthor(new String(book.getAuthor()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using AdditionalInfo as the payload. I'm sending a Request, and that's the type expected by the endpoint as well. The AdditionalInfo is in the name/value "map" of the Request. Regarding your question about whether Request and AdditionalInfo are related, no, they're not. That's the point. For reasons too tedious to go into here, the request contains any number of name/value pairs collected before calling the endpoint.

Comment: I get your point about adding see-also to the request, and that worked, but the goal was to not have to do that for every type that can go in the args.

Comment: @user1461450 You are using `JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class, AdditionalInfo.class);` and expect, that the context can switch from `Request` to `AdditionalInfo`. But that's not the way it is done. The JAXBFramework is doing something like: `JAXBContext jaxbContext = jaxbResolver.getContext(type);` where type is either `Request.class` or `AdditionalInfo.class`. Once the JaxbContext was resolved, you can't switch between them. The encapsulation of a data entity into another isn't the way how the communication is intented to be done.

Comment: @user1461450 For example, you also don't declare a method like: `void doSth(Request request){...}` and try to call it with arguments of type `List<AdditionalInfo> request`. This won't work even if `AdditionalInfo` extends `Request`! The way you will solve this is to create data enitiy classes and use them as argument types in your rest endpoint methods instead of `public String doProblem(Request request) {...}`

Comment: Adding see also fixed the problem. It's just disappointing that RESTEasy, upon encountering a properly XML-annotated class that it hasn't seen before, doesn't simply create a JAXBContext for it on the fly, and cache it. The current implementation requires users of the framework to tell the framework every type it's going to encounter, and, worse, to do that by adding see-also annotations to associate unrelated types. Suppose I just want to send a heterogenous collection of Objects. Now I have to tell RESTEasy the type of every Object ahead of time.

Comment: @user1461450 No, if you follow the suggestions from my last post, you don't have to specify any types at all! I will add a test case from one of my projects, which shows that you never have to add any type information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43943/discussion-between-user1461450-and-my-name-is)

Answer (score 0):

Took the discussion off to chat, and refined the question to be generic enough that it highlighted the problem. Restated, the problem is, given this endpoint:

```
@POST 
@Path("example/v1") 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
public String foo(List<Object> bars) throws Exception {...
```

and where we don't know ahead of time the types of the Objects in the list, or how many there are, only that they are all root elements that are properly JAXB-annotated, and knowing we can't assume any sort of inheritance or composition relationships among the objects, how can we call that endpoint method via RESTEasy.

The answer, courtesy of user My-Name-Is, is to write a custom message-body writer and reader.

The way I envisioned RESTEasy working (really, how I envisioned JAXB working): Get the class of each Object. If seen already, then get the cached JAXBContext. If not seen already, get the Annotations off the Object's class, see if it is JAXB-annotated, if so create a JAXBContext for it and add it to the cache, else throw exception.

But it appears JAXB does no such thing.

By the way, the reason I have to deal with these weird unrelated objects is that the request is passing info about a set of function calls that are recorded on the client, and then "played back" on the server. So the request is just a shell over a list of calls, and each call can have N arguments, and the types of the arguments aren't necessarily known by the request.

An analogy would be that the request is a bus, taking people with various skills from one location, where they have been handed tools to do their jobs, to another location, where they are supposed to do their jobs. The bus doesn't know anything about skills or tools. It just knows how to transport arbitrary people from one place to another.